# ScrollView doesn't work on iPad but works on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview and it is full off buttons. this scrollview work iphone but not work on ipad

```
#define scrollViewSizeForiPad 1000 
#define scrollViewSizeForiPhone 600 
#define locationButtonSizeForiPhone 50 
#define locationButtonSizeForiPad 30
```

i added buttons like this

```
lc_button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize, buttonSize);
[_uiScrollForLocations addSubview:lc_button];
```

---

and some labels

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    buttonSize = buttonWidthHeightForiPad;
    lc_label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    lc_label.frame = CGRectMake(3, 100, buttonSize, 20);
} else {
    buttonSize = buttonWidthHeightForiPhone;
    lc_label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9];
    lc_label.frame = CGRectMake(8, 50, buttonSize, 10);
}
[_uiScrollForLocations addSubview:lc_label];


-(void) showLocations:(NSMutableArray *)lc_array {
[self hideAllLocations];
[self addButtonToView:lc_array whichView:_uiScrollForLocations type:@"Location"];

CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = _uiScrollForLocations.frame.size;
int viewHeight;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    viewHeight = buttonWidthHeightForiPad;
} else {
    viewHeight = buttonWidthHeightForiPhone;
}
_uiScrollForLocations.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width, viewHeight);}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happen because contentSize <= _uiScrollForLocations.frame

Need set

`_uiScrollForLocations.alwaysBounceVertical = YES`

or

`_uiScrollForLocations.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES`

Comment: starts scrolling but it return the first place, not stay where i want. Do you have any idea to handle his situation? Thanks.

Comment: @kozer, need to make bigger contentSize